# What does "spin on" mean?

Tags: integrated-circuit, mems

In the begining of section 17.2 (chapter 17) of [Digital Integrated Circuits: Analysis and Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=QHtalNXHKbsC) the auther says:

> There are positive and negative resists. The use of a positive resist
>   for pattern transfer is illustrated in Figure 17.1. First, a fresh
>   layer of silicon dioxide is grown over the entire wafer. Then, the
>   wafer is coated with a thin layer of positive photoresist. This
>   photoresist is **spun on** and then baked to the desired hardness.

I understand most of the text, but I cant't understand the meaning of "spun on".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_coating):

> Spin coating is a procedure used to deposit uniform thin films to flat
>   substrates. Usually a small amount of coating material is applied on
>   the center of the substrate, which is either spinning at low speed or
>   not spinning at all. The substrate is then rotated at high speed in
>   order to spread the coating material by centrifugal force. A machine
>   used for spin coating is called a spin coater, or simply spinner.

Comment: Exactly that. Its a very simple and quick method to ensure uniform coverage and uniform thickness of the resist.

Answer (score 1):

The substrate is spinning to evenly distribute the media being applied.

Here's an example:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_zoeeR3geTA#t=53